# Getting indirect function to change range when dragging across cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

Having trouble getting the `AC2:AC150` to change to `AD2:AD150` when dragging the formula across cells. There are some slightly similar solutions on the board for this, but I'm having trouble implementing them. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!$a$2:$A$150"),$C18,INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!Ac2:Ac150"))
```

Comment: Since `Ac2:Ac150` is typed as a string, it won't change by dragging. And you can’t just type it as a cell reference after the string, because `INDIRECT` requires a string or a reference to a string (which is a reference to a cell or range). This is why you need Tom’s answer. See my comment for complete syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than having the string AC2:AC150 before the final brackets, try putting

```
ADDRESS(ROW(AC2),COLUMN(AC2),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(AC150),COLUMN(AC150),4)
```

then when you drag the formula across it will change AC to AD and the ADDRESS function will pick up the new column number.

Comment: Good answer. The full code should be `=SUMIF(INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!$A$2:$A$150"),$C18,INDIRECT("'"&$A$3&"'!"&ADDRESS(ROW(AC2),COLUMN(AC2),4)&":"&ADDRESS(ROW(AC150),COLUMN(AC150),4)))`. Note that I entered your code after the `"` and then added the `&`.

Comment: Thank you, it would have been clearer if I had entered the full formula including the & !